# Concat the resulting value in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can i concat result value and then send the final value as output.

```
WHILE(LENGTH(totalexpenseamount )>0) DO
        BEGIN
              SET totalshipmentexpenseamount = CONCAT(totalshipmentexpenseamount,',',indshipmentexpenseamount);
END;
    END WHILE;
```

but at end totalshipmentexpenseamount  does not have any value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know what is before the code that you presented, but you can try the following:

```
WHILE(LENGTH(totalexpenseamount )>0) DO
        BEGIN
              SET totalshipmentexpenseamount = CONCAT(COALESCE(totalshipmentexpenseamount, ''),',',indshipmentexpenseamount);
END;
    END WHILE;
```

this is because `totalshipmentexpenseamount` is set to `null`in the first time and when you concat `null` with other thing it comes out `null`. The `coalesce` will return empty if `totalshipmentexpenseamount` is `null`

**EDIT:**

Change to this

```
WHILE(LENGTH(totalexpenseamount )>0) DO
BEGIN
    SET totalshipmentexpenseamount = COALESCE(CONCAT(totalshipmentexpenseamount,',',indshipmentexpenseamount), indshipmentexpenseamount);
END;
WHILE;
```

Since you have concatenation with a comma, this will set in the first pass the value of `indshipmentexpenseamount` otherwise will concat the `totalshipmentexpenseamount` with a comma and the `indshipmentexpenseamount`

Comment: when i use this code i get error like Data truncated for column

Comment: The amount of data you're putting in totalshipmentexpenseamount  exceeds its definition. See the column definition an the length of the string you're putting into it

Comment: Your code returns a `double` and but the `totalshipmentexpenseamount` is a `text`. Print the value of `totalshipmentexpenseamount` after the `END WHILE` and see what it has got.

Comment: i corrected that. but i am getting output like ,1398.01,289.83. extra , is coming at beginning